# Python + Keras. Что делать после того, как обучил модель?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras

Только начал втягиваться в либу Keras. Что делать после того, как обучил модель? Я имею ввиду, ее нужно как то упаковать или залить, чтобы использовать или развернуть в других проектах? Как это сделать? В Keras есть model.save('test.h5'), этого достаточно, чтобы развернуть где то еще? Скажем, есть необходимость чтобы модель оценивала картинку в приложении, в таком случае, после обучения, как запаковать модель или залить обученную модель куда то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загруженная модель полностью готова к использованию (предсказаниям):

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('/path/to/saved_model.h5')
```

Стоит упомянуть, что необходимые для работы модели модули (`Keras`, `Tensorflow` / `Theano`, etc.) должны быть установлены на той машине, где вы собираетесь использовать обученную модель.